# NotSupportedException when using GroupBy() and Timeout() without Where()

Tags: c#, nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate

I'm trying to perform the following query with a stateless session.

```
var products = session.Query<Product>().Timeout(5 * 60)
                .GroupBy(p => p.ProductType)
                .Select(p => new {ProductType = e.Key, Count = e.LongCount()}).ToList();
```

It results in a NotSupportedException, the following code does however work fine

```
var products = session.Query<Product>().Timeout(5 * 60)
                .Where(p => true)
                .GroupBy(p => p.ProductType)
                .Select(p => new {ProductType = e.Key, Count = e.LongCount()}).ToList();

var products = session.Query<Product>()                    
                .GroupBy(p => p.ProductType)
                .Select(p => new {ProductType = e.Key, Count = e.LongCount()}).Timeout(5 * 60).ToList();
```

Why do I need the Where() if I add Timeout() and why does it work if Timeout() is last?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar to nHibernate, but I suppose that `Timeout()` method returns object of type that cannot be extended by `GroupBy()` extention method. So you can try explicit cast:

```
var products = (IEnumerable<Product>)(session.Query<Product>().Timeout(5 * 60))
                .GroupBy(p => p.ProductType)
                .Select(p => new {ProductType = e.Key, Count = e.LongCount()}).ToList();
```

Comment: .Timeout() returns the same type as session.Query<Product>().Where(), IQueryable<Product>

Comment: @andy.e, try to switch that object to `IEnumerable` with `AsEnumerable()` method. There can be some mess with `IEnumerable`/`IQuerable` extention and objects' own methods implementation.